# La URL aparece como tachada

Tags: soporte, usuarios

Estaba viendo la siguiente pregunta en SO en español, [clic aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/144299/sintaxis-en-codici%C3%B3n-es-correcta-no-entra-al-elseif).

Lo que me llamó mucho la atención, fue que la OP tiene su nombre tachado aunque pensé que hasta ahí todo 'normal', lo curioso fue al acceder a su perfil. La URL aparece tachada también.

Tal cual no creo que sea un bug de SO, dudo mucho porque es algo externo (según mis pocos conocimientos). Pero ¿A qué se debe esto? Nunca lo había visto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿̶A̶ ̶q̶u̶é̶ ̶t̶e̶ ̶e̶s̶t̶á̶s̶ ̶r̶e̶f̶i̶r̶i̶e̶n̶d̶o̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶ ̶"̶t̶a̶c̶h̶a̶d̶o̶"̶?̶

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se debe a que el nombre de usuario en cuestión hace uso de caracteres especiales ya que estos se permiten en la red de sitios de Stack Exchange.

Al codificarse el URL resultante queda de la siguiente forma

`https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/39994/r%CC%B6o%CC%B6c%CC%B6i%CC%B6o%CC%B6-p%C3%A9rez`

Lo que realmente identifica a usuarios en un sitio de la red de Stack Exchange es el número entre `users/` y el siguiente `/`. Cabe destacar que este número "podría" ser distinto para un mismo usuario en los distintos sitios de Stack Exchange a los que se una.

Nota: La pregunta referida ha sido eliminada.

Comment: Efectivamente. De hecho, no _podría_ sino que casi seguro que es distinto, pues los usuarios se crean independientemente en cada sitio y sería mucha casualidad que el autoincrement estuviera en la misma posición.